# OpenRAVE ControllerBase is blocking at the IsDone() method and never returns

Tags: c++, openrave

I am working on a custom OpenRAVE `ControllerBase` C++ class that implements a robot controller.

I will try to keep the code as minimal as possible:

```
typedef actionlib::SimpleActionClient<control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction> TrajClient;

class ArmController : public ControllerBase {

    .
    .
    .

    virtual bool SetPath(TrajectoryBaseConstPtr ptraj) {
        if (ptraj != NULL) {
            TrajectoryBasePtr traj = SimplifyTrajectory(ptraj);

            PlannerStatus status = planningutils::RetimeTrajectory(traj, false, 1.0, 1.0, "LinearTrajectoryRetimer");
            if (status != PS_HasSolution) {
                ROS_ERROR("Not executing trajectory because retimer failed.");
                return false;
            }

            trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory trajectory = FromOpenRaveToRosTrajectory(traj);
            control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryGoal goal;
            goal.trajectory = trajectory;
            _ac->sendGoal(goal);
        }

        return true;
    }

    virtual bool IsDone() {
      _ac->waitForResult(ros::Duration(5.0));
      if (_ac->getState() == actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState::SUCCEEDED) {
        return true;
      }
    }
}
```

This is a single controller for the robot arm, and I have implemented another one for the end-effector which is not currently in use (the end-effector is disconnected) in this case but it does some basic operations (like open, close gripper and listen to its joint state).

Then I have a Python script that tries to execute a trajectory on the robot:

```
robot.multicontroller = RaveCreateMultiController(env, "")
robot.SetController(robot.multicontroller)

robot_controller = RaveCreateController(env, 'arm_controller')
robot.multicontroller.AttachController(robot_controller, [2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6], 0)

hand_controller = RaveCreateController(env, 'gripper_controller')
robot.multicontroller.AttachController(hand_controller, [3], 0)

trajectory_object = some_trajectory_object

robot.GetController().SetPath(trajectory_object)
robot.WaitForController(0)
```

The trajectory is being executed on the real robot with success but the code blocks at `robot.WaitForController(0)` and is actually in an endless loop in `IsDone()` method of the controller.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your end-effector controller also implements a similar `IsDone()` method with a similar logic (i.e is waiting for the end-effector to reach its goal to return true, otherwise is returning false).

Since you are using a [`MultiController`](http://openrave.org/docs/0.8.2/coreapihtml/classOpenRAVE_1_1MultiController.html#a4eedf9afc8b39fe107281f97aec13e9a) the `WaitForController(0)` in your Python script is not looking only to the arm controller but to all of the controllers attached to the `MultiController`.

From [`bool OpenRAVE::MultiController::IsDone() virtual`](http://openrave.org/docs/0.8.2/coreapihtml/classOpenRAVE_1_1MultiController.html#a4eedf9afc8b39fe107281f97aec13e9a)

> returns true only if all controllers return true.

Since you said that one of the controllers (the end-effector controller) is not in use, the `IsDone` of this controller returns `false` and hence the `WaitForController(0)` of the MultiController is blocked not on the arm controller you are suspecting, but instead is waiting for this not-in-use end-effector controller `IsDone` to evaluate to `true`, which will never do because you have it disconnected from the system; hence the blocking.

You have I think three options:

- You either make sure that the end-effector is also connected to the system and hence the end-effector controller is working as expected (i.e the IsDone is returning True).
- You are not attaching the end-effector controller to the multi-controller in your Python script (comment it out).
- You change the logic of the `IsDone` method of the end-effector controller such that if is not connected, will return true.

Here is a quick solution:

```
def _is_rostopic_name_exists(self, topic_name):
    if topic_name[0] != "/":
        topic_name = "/" + topic_name

    topics = rospy.get_published_topics()
    for topic in topics:
        if topic[0] == topic_name:
            return True

    return False

if _is_rostopic_name_exists("CModelRobotInput") and _is_rostopic_name_exists("CModelRobotOutput"):
    hand_controller = RaveCreateController(env, 'robotiqcontroller')
    robot.multicontroller.AttachController(hand_controller, [3], 0)
else:
    RaveLogWarn("End-effector controller not attached, topics ('CModelRobotInput' or/and 'CModelRobotOutput') are not available.")
```

This way we are attaching the second controller to the multi-controller iff certain, required, ROS topics exist that are needed for the normal execution of that controller.